# Can I use google assistant library in python program without raspberry pi?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have been looking a lot to use google assistant in a python program, but all I found was to create a personal assistant using raspberry pi. I just want to use the google assistant library in a program on my laptop and not raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use the same Python scripts across platforms. A raspberry pi is a handy device for putting together an embedded device, but isn't necessary. The gRPC calls will work anywhere. The library does have certain restrictions to work with either the raspberry pi or Ubuntu.